# Short-lived download URL from Firebase iOS SDK

Tags: ios, firebase

Is there any way to get a short-lived download URL via the Firebase iOS SDK for Firebase Storage files? I don't see anything in `FirebaseStorage.StorageReference` but apparently Google Cloud [allows for signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) so maybe there's some way of doing it at the Google Cloud layer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to generate an auto-expiring, read-only URL through the Firebase SDKs. The Firebase SDKs can generate download URLs, which are valid until they are revoked.

If you want a URL that auto-expires, you'll have to generate a so-called [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) with one of the Google Cloud, server-side SDKs.